# Заход на страницу и пара кликов по JavaScript ссылке

Tags: php, javascript

Скрипт должен зайти на страницу http://sait.ru/test/vasya и сделать клик по javascript ссылке типа:

```
<a id="ctl00_cph_data_ctl01_lbToggleOfferTr" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$cph$data$ctl01$lbToggleOfferTr", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>vasya</a>
```

После чего должен произойти клик по кнопке:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cph$data$ctl01$oiOfferInfo$btSendProposal" value="Подать заявку" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cph$data$ctl01$oiOfferInfo$btSendProposal&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_cph_data_ctl01_oiOfferInfo_btSendProposal">
```

После чего он должен сделать паузу в 2 секунды и снова сделать клики и так проделать 10 раз. Но самое страшное здесь - в следующий раз надо сделать клики уже по другой ссылке javascript и кнопке. Но во всех кнопках и ссылках совпадают некоторые части. В ссылке:

```
_lbToggleOfferTr" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ct
```

В кнопке:

```
$oiOfferInfo$btSendProposal" value="Подать заявку" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ct
```

Как такое сделать на PHP?

Comment: Тут пахнет автокликером/накрутчиком. И если раньше подобное не писали, а из вопроса именно это следует, то начните с простого, маленький грабер значений с любого сайта, потом напишите просто кликер по ссылкам, а потом уже и JS атакуйте.

Comment: trec, это совсем не накрутчик. Просто нужно автоматизировать выполнение однотипной рутиной работы. В итоге все сделал за ~10-20 мин с помощью iMacros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще мне кажется это легче сделать [плагин к браузеру на javascript (Хром)](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/google_chrome/75639/), который будет делать все, что вы перечислили. А так вам понадобиться:

1. [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/) (или аналогично средство под ваш браузер) для выискивание логики в javascript файлах сайта, т.е. как генерятся данные для отправки формы на сервер. Так же он вам поможет определить какие даные отправляются на сервер.
2. [curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php), он будет для вас "эмулировать браузер" от запроса к запросу на удаленный сайт;
3. терпение и еще раз терпение :).